# Matching json parsed value with user entered value

Tags: java, android, regex, json, scope

I parsed json to adapt for my autocompleteTextView. I tried to match the value parsed by my json object with the value entered by user.

But some where i am failing. please help me in matching these values.

i have to match the string(acity) that is entered by user with my parsed json value stored in responseList.

This is how i am trying.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

                new HttpGetTask().execute();

                Button shwBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showBtn);

                shwBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        AutoCompleteTextView city1 = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCity);
                        EditText area1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edArea);

                        String aCity = city1.getText().toString().trim();
                        String aArea = area1.getText().toString().trim();

                        //here i have to match acity with all the values in responseList before sending it to next activity

                            Intent myInt = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                                    Map1Activity.class);

                            String city = city1.getText().toString();
                            String area = area1.getText().toString();
                            myInt.putExtra("city", city);
                            myInt.putExtra("area", area);
                            startActivity(myInt);


                    }
                });

            }

            private class HttpGetTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

                String URL = "xyzz.cities.json?app_id=test";
                AndroidHttpClient mClient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("");

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    // http stuff
        return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray json = new JSONArray(result);

        //getting my response(cities)
        Log.v("ResponseCity", result);

                        final List<String> responseList = new ArrayList<String>();

                        for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                            final JSONObject e = json.getJSONObject(i);

                            String name = e.getString("name");
//Adding all values to a stringList
                            responseList.add(name);

                            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
                            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SearchActivity.this,
                                    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                                    responseList);
                            AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCity);
                            textView.setAdapter(adapter);

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (null != mClient)
                        mClient.close();
                }

            }
```

Comment: You would just need to loop responseList and for each iteration compare the String in the iteration with the string acity in each iteration. Is it possible to elaborate on what you plan to achieve?

Comment: @cokeby190 i'm not getting "where" to loop and match both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So lets assume you need to match a certain city before you intent to a map :

```
 private final List<String> responseList;

      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

            new HttpGetTask().execute();

            Button shwBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showBtn);

            shwBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    AutoCompleteTextView city1 = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCity);
                    EditText area1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edArea);

                    String aCity = city1.getText().toString().trim();
                    String aArea = area1.getText().toString().trim();

                    //here i have to match acity with all the values in responseList before sending it to next activity

                    for(int i=0; i<responseList.size(); i++) {

                        if(responseList.get(i).equals(aCity)) {
                            Intent myInt = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                                Map1Activity.class);

                            String city = city1.getText().toString();
                            String area = area1.getText().toString();
                            myInt.putExtra("city", city);
                            myInt.putExtra("area", area);
                            startActivity(myInt);
                        }

                    }
                }
            });

        }

        private class HttpGetTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            String URL = "xyzz.cities.json?app_id=test";
            AndroidHttpClient mClient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("");

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // http stuff
    return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                try {
                    JSONArray json = new JSONArray(result);

    //getting my response(cities)
    Log.v("ResponseCity", result);

                    responseList = new ArrayList<String>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                        final JSONObject e = json.getJSONObject(i);

                        String name = e.getString("name");
//Adding all values to a stringList
                        responseList.add(name);

                        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
                        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SearchActivity.this,
                                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                                responseList);
                        AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCity);
                        textView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (null != mClient)
                    mClient.close();
            }

        }
```

It should be something like that if I didnt guess your intent wrongly.